# Edits - How can I reject

Tags: discussion

Evening

I made a post - nothing wrong with it, yet a user decided to edit it - does he have nothing else to do except collect points for edits?

Waste of time in my opinion.

Yes, I said Evening and Signed off with my name.

Comment: This is not the forum for raising this concern. And FYI any edit is reviewed by moderator also other than the post owner

Comment: I also feel that some of the edits are made only to earn points and not to improve quality of questions.

Answer (score 7):

I think "farming" reputation by edits is not such a big deal, as long as the edits have [a certain quality and meet the SP.SE standards](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/editing):

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
> - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
> - To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
> - To add related resources or hyperlinks

So it's (most) the moderators / people with 2k reputation "job" to decide whether an edit is worth accepting it. Maybe some "trivial" edits have passed the queue which should have not. **But I think the "2k people" are doing a good review job in general.**

The permission to "reject" edits to your own posts might result in situation like that:

> Why's that guy editing my post? It was perfect the way it was. Edit rejected!

But what's a perfect post in the StackExchange world is not a decision to be made by a single (new) user but by the community and/or the people that have been around for a while (see: [Jeff Atwood: A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) )

And the maximum reputation you can gain from editing posts is set to 1,000. So "fiddling" reputation by extensive editing is only possible to a limited extent.

> When an edit is approved, the editor receives +2 reputation -- up to a maximum of +1000 total per user. Contributing good edits is now a nice way to gain reputation and bootstrap less active users into full members of the community.

(see: [Jeff Atwood: Suggested Edits and Edit Review](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/))

[But as Daniel Ziga pointed out on meta](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/how-can-we-make-users-include-more-details-and-ask-better-questions), SP.SE seems to have "problems" with (new) users posting poorly formatted questions:

> 4. As an extension of point 3. New users don't know how to format their question. Moderators spend a lot of time editing questions to improve code formatting [...]

I think it's not just about code formatting. I often see "copy-paste-one-liner" posts that are "optically" difficult to read. And I really feel like:

> "Gosh. You don't put effort in formatting your post and making it pleasant to read. But you want the community to help?! Next."

Many posts from new users **really need** grammar fixing and formatting improvement (as the new user are probably not aware of the formatting options, as Daniel said in his post.)

So there are some people that format other people's posts. I think (hope) their intention is not to boost their own reputation but to make the post more readable so that other people are more willing to deal with the problem described / hidden in the one-liner.

And now imagine this post without formatting ... just kidding :)

Answer (score 2):

Just for your record:

1. I edit posts to ensure that the `user` receive "maximum" views for asking a good question.
2. My reason behind formatting a post as per SE standards is plainly because I feel using formatting options provided by SE is to help the search engine find the accurate question a user is searching for. Using `` option or a

   > Block quote

   aids the search engine to tap these formatted words as keywords and find a better match

Comment: As a side note: ` ` is mainly used for code snippets on SP.SE, marking the questions keywords as code really only lowers the readability

Comment: Sure, I will keep this in mind